# Magento 2 (v2.1.2) - Choosing separate theme for product page

Tags: magento2, product, theme, magento-2.1, design

I am currently trying to setup an individual custom theme specifically for **some** products. I have another custom theme which will style/structure the rest of the site along with its own product page styling. However, this doesn't seem to work. It still uses the structure from the "master theme" and only takes the styles/assets from the selected alternate custom theme chosen inside the products admin in **Schedule Design Update**.

Here is the structure for the "master" theme which structures everything BUT the products that get told otherwise.

[image: Master theme folder structure]

This theme is working as expected and, whilst testing I dropped in the XML file to this theme which structures the rest of the site, it creates the expected layout.
Here is the structure for the "alternate" product theme, which the XML doesn't **seem** to get recognised at all, no matter which XML file inside `Magento_Theme > layout`.

[image]

Can anyone spot a problem in how both themes have been setup? The "alternate" theme is **not** a child of the master theme, however this has been tried too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `Schedule Design Update` feature of Magento2 for Individual product.Just open any product in backend and check this tab

[image]

Comment: Hi Keyur, as mentioned above, i've already tried this, however it only pulls through the styles from the alternate theme, and not the XML files!